# How to set Background image properly in to my code

Tags: flutter

I want to set background image in to my code but I got this error "Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/Onepiece-1.jpg"  this one is the error actually it is not an error but the image doesn't appear in the background. I already set my image to in pubspec.yml.I just don't know how to set properly in my code and i dont know what the problem is can some one help my how to fix this error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Registration Form',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Registration'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController2 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController3 = TextEditingController();
   bool showPassword = false;
  TextEditingController nameController4 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController5 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController6 = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {},
          label: Text('Register'),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.upload_file_sharp),
        ),
        
        body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/Onepiece-1.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),


        
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Username',
                ),
                onChanged: (Text) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              )),
                      
        
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController2,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Email Address',
                ),
                onChanged: (Text) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              )),

          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController3,
                obscureText: showPassword,
                obscuringCharacter: "*",
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                ),

                onChanged: (Text) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              )),
            

          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController4,
                obscureText: showPassword,
                obscuringCharacter: "*",
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                ),

                onChanged: (Text) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              )),
              TextButton(
         onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
                  showPassword = !showPassword;
           });
         },
         child: Text('Show / Hide Password')
         ),
            

          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController5,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Address',
                ),
                onChanged: (Text) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              )),


          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController6,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Phone Number',
                ),
                onChanged: (Text) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              )),



        ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: You most likely didn’t write the file name correctly in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I ran your code and it worked without any problems. Please enter the error code

Comment: "Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/Onepiece-1.jpg"  this one is the error actually it is not an error but the image doesn't appear in the background.

Comment: Could you show the `asset linking code` and your `asset directory` in `pubspec.yaml`?
The error seems to have occurred because the asset link code and the image path of the actual asset directory are different.

Answer (score 0):

***assets Directory***

[image]

***pubspec.yaml***

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

***source code***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Registration Form',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Registration'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController2 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController3 = TextEditingController();
  bool showPassword = false;
  TextEditingController nameController4 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController5 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController6 = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {},
          label: Text('Register'),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.upload_file_sharp),
        ),

        body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/1-1.JPG"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),



            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Username',
                        ),
                        onChanged: (Text) {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      )),


                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: nameController2,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Email Address',
                        ),
                        onChanged: (Text) {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      )),

                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: nameController3,
                        obscureText: showPassword,
                        obscuringCharacter: "*",
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Password',
                        ),

                        onChanged: (Text) {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      )),


                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: nameController4,
                        obscureText: showPassword,
                        obscuringCharacter: "*",
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                        ),

                        onChanged: (Text) {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      )),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          showPassword = !showPassword;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text('Show / Hide Password')
                  ),


                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: nameController5,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Address',
                        ),
                        onChanged: (Text) {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      )),


                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: nameController6,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Phone Number',
                        ),
                        onChanged: (Text) {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      )),



                ])));
  }
}
```